# What is the required torque to rotate a 50mm aluminimum plate of weight 100g?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, torque

I have a aluminium plate of radius 50mm and thickness 4mm. How much torque is needed to rotate it?

In case additional information is required :

I have a RS 380 motor, but I guess torque required is irrespective of motor. 
How do you calculate torque of other round plate sizes? Like 60mm or 55mm.

What is approximatively the exact torque for 50mm?

[image: aluminium plate]

[![motor][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: Will the plate be attached to the motor and hang in midair? Or will it be touching something else, which would generate friction? If it's suspended in midair, then any amount of torque supplied by any motor would be sufficient to rotate the plate. Obviously, a larger motor will impart a greater rotational acceleration to the plate.

Comment: The required acceleration is the key piece of information you need to answer this question, assuming nothing else is attached to the motor.

Comment: As @Ethan48 points out, $\tau=I\alpha$, where $I$ depends on the geometry, $\tau$ is the torque, and $\alpha$ is the required angular acceleration. Without the latter information, torque has little meaning.

Comment: Along what axis do you want to rotate it? How fast? How much acceleration? Is there any drag (friction) on it?

Comment: @Wasabi a hole will be made in the center of the plate and attached to motor, and yes it will be rotated in mid air. No it won't touch anything else. I want to rotate the plate at 5000rpm , and in case if this detail is required : i am just letting you know,that the motor has a top speed of 18000. For motor details i guess Google would suffice. Would it need other detail. pls reply me.

Comment: @Ethan48 i am sorry , i guess i have very little knowledge about these terms , though if you make a basic search about details in google and answer me , i would be really grateful . Though i am attaching a chart of the motor in my question. I would like to have the max torque(in my case i want to know the weight) it could rotate. speed could be anything from 6000-15000rpm doesnt matter. Though i would love to know the approx RPM as well. Thanks

Comment: @DaveTweed i want to make a hole at the base of the plate and put the motor shaft into it and jam it woth hot glue and then rotate it. I dont know , what drag you talking about but i dont think there will be any, as i wan it to rotate freely in open air .

Comment: @starrise Thank you for the help. :D Though i need a little more favour from you guys , and i can see that coming,. Thanks again

Comment: Put all this new information **in the question** so that those trying to answer don't have to trawl through the comments. "_... though if you make a basic search about details in google and answer me ..._" sounds as though you want someone else to do a web search for you. Your question doesn't show any sign of research.

Answer (score 1):

Force is required to accelerate mass and overcome friction force. So the torque required in steady rpm only as big as the friction.

Comment: right, note at 5000rpm the air drag will be substantial.  googling "aerodynamic drag spinning disk" might proove fruitful